# Using Enzyme simulate on custom events?

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, enzyme

It is possible to use Enzyme's method .simulate() on custom events.
For Example:

```
// Code
<Element onFoo={someFunction}></Elements>

// Test
const element = shallow(<Element>);
element.simulate('foo');
```

Is this the way custom events should be tested with Enzyme or is it a better approach to use s.th. like:

```
//Test
const element = shallow(<Element>);
element.props.onFoo()
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `.simulate()` for custom events is not implemented. There is an [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/147) on github, where this topic is discussed and one of the *Enzyme* maintainers suggests to use the second approach you've provided:

```
wrapper.find(Child).prop('customEvent')(fakeEvent)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. simulate() woks on custom events as long as the on.. is in front of it (for example onFoo). I am just wandering if api changes will crash my tests, because i am 'misusing' the simulate() method, or isn't it a misusage and the implementation is fine as is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.simulate()` on custom events. There is a catch that you have to use `on` as a prefix for the custom event. For eg. `onJump`, `onAdd` is how you have to name your custom events.

`element.props.onFoo()` in the above case is not really testing the functionality. It only tests the internals of component so the binding remains untested. Also it becomes difficult to refactor as implementation is coupled with test code.

You can refer to this [blog](https://blog.mavenhive.in/testing-custom-events-with-enzyme-react-ed63d9744f18) for a working demo of the scenario and how components having custom events can be tested.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, if you are testing a parent component that uses your `Element` component:

Not sure if this is a matter of version as well. But I'm working with enzyme 2.9.1 and this is how I accomplish to trigger a child custom function:

`wrapper.find(Child).prop('customEvent')(/*args*/)`

Answer (score 1):

But isn't it actually already working in the current shallow rendering?

```
/* Film component */
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <FilmHeader onSearchClick={this.handleSearchClick}>
    ...
  )
}

/* Test */
const wrapper = shallow(<Film {...props} />);
wrapper.find('FilmHeader').simulate('searchClick');
```

The aforementioned enzyme [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/147) is still open though. And documentation doesn't state anything obvious about this feature. So maybe the issue is the documentation itself.

Comment: The above code works fine for me, at least with Enzyme 3 and React 16.

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN A., not sure I get your `., may be in previously.` edit, could you rephrase please?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, trying to siumlate a custom event on a component that is not the top-level component was as follows:

```
const myComponent = enzymeWrapper.find('MyComponent');
myComponent.node.onThingSelected({}, { thing: newThing});
```

Where myComponent is a React component, onThingSelected is the custom event handler exactly as named on the component, and newThing is an object of the type expected by the event handler.