# How to simulate onChange on material-ui autoComplete component and check the state value using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I need to simulate an onChange event with enzyme to update a state's component that is not working, I share the component's code in order to be helped.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const options = [{ value: 'Option 1'}, {value: 'Option 2'}]

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0])

  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.value === value.value}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI Autocomplete is a wrapper to input tag. The event onChange is binded with input tag and not with Autocomplete component. One Possible solution would be to use custom events to test.

```
const controllableComponent = enzyme.mount(<ControllableStates {...props} />;
const autocompleteComponent = controllableComponent.find(Autocomplete)
autocompleteComponent().prop('onChange', event, value)
```

[using-enzyme-simulate-on-custom-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767177/using-enzyme-simulate-on-custom-events)

Comment: Please add the appropiate tags to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Autocomplete gets the chosen value/option from the 2nd param from the onChange call, rather than from `event.target.value` like most other compponents does. You simple just have to add your value/option as the following param after the event in the `simulate` call.

Example:

```
const w = shallow(React.createElement(YourComponent, props))

const event = {};
const firstOption = w.find(Autocomplete).props().options[0];
w.find(Autocomplete).simulate('change', event, firstOption);
```